# Laravel type-hinting for Datetime

Tags: laravel, type-hinting

```
/**
 * 
 * @param date $nextDate
 *
 */
public function updateXXXX($nextDate)
{
    ....
}
```

I am using laravel 6.X and when i used phpstan in my code i got below type hinting error for
**has invalid typehint type** so can anybody guide for this small fix.

Comment: Would [PHPDoc Types](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types) help in any way? There is no `date` type